# Link in Nested Forms returning Invalid Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, associations, nested-forms

I'm using Nested Forms to create a complex list of forms for a group of models associated with it. However, when I add the link_to_add link in my form it returns an error message,

Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :workout_exercises association.

If I remove the link everything works fine. I have to assume it's a view error since removing it causes no issues and I imagine would bring up an issue if my associations or accepted nested forms for wasn't working. What's wrong with my code and how do I fix it.

```
= nested_form_for(@client_workout) do |f|

  = f.number_field :client_id, placeholder: "Client's Name"

  = f.text_field :description, placeholder: "description"

  = f.text_field :note, placeholder: "notes"

  = f.fields_for :workouts do |workout_form|
    = workout_form.text_field :name, placeholder: "Workout Name"

    = workout_form.fields_for :workout_exercises do |exercise_details_form|
      div Create an Exercise

      = exercise_details_form.fields_for :exercise do |exercise_form|
        = exercise_form.text_field :name, placeholder: "Exercise Name"

      = exercise_details_form.text_field :reps, placeholder: "reps"

      = exercise_details_form.text_field :sets, placeholder: "sets"

      = exercise_details_form.text_field :weight, placeholder: "weight"

      = exercise_details_form.text_field :category, placeholder: "category"

      = exercise_details_form.link_to_remove "Remove this exercise", class: "btn btn-danger"

    / This line of code below is causing the problem
    = workout_form.link_to_add "Add this exercise", :workout_exercises

  = f.submit class: "btn btn-success"
```

My `client_workout` model

```
class ClientWorkout < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :workout_id, :description, :note

  belongs_to :workout

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout
end
```

Comment: Please post your client_workout model

Comment: Posted it in question.

Answer (score 0):

You should invert it because `workout` has many `workout_clients`

```
= nested_form_for(@workout) do |f|
```

And

```
= f.fields_for :client_workouts do |clientworkout_form|
```